# Sharepoint 2010: How to dynamically change the view of a list in a web part

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have a page with a list of companies and a list of related data.
I can connect the lists so that when I select a company, I only see that company's related data. Fine.
However I now need to also change the view of the list of related data. e.g. "Company1" has view "Company1" with one set of columns and filtering, "Company2" has view "Company2" with another set of columns and filtering, etc.

I don't believe this is possible using standard page editing, so customisation is required.
I haven't got access to the server, so I would prefer a JavaScript solution to this if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just setup three pages, with each correct view inserted into the page. then from you menu just select the pages, Company 1 View Company 2 View etc. Nothing complicated

Comment: That's what I have done but each page is quite complex and once start adding conditional formatting etc it will be quite an effort to maintain 8 pages. But thanks anyway